# Google Api Search Result is not working

Tags: php, google-api-client

To get the search result from google, I used those code. Sometimes it work perfectly but sometimes it don't give any answer. Now don't know what is the problem. I need those result for research purpose so I had to browse for different query

```
 if (isset($_GET['content'])) {
   // echo $_GET['content'];

  $url_all=NULL;
  $visibleurl=NULL;
  $title_all=NULL;
  $content_all=NULL;
  $mainstring=NULL;

  $searchTerm=$_GET['content'];
    $endpoint = 'web';
    $key= 'angelic-bazaar-111103';
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/".$endpoint;

    $args['q'] = $searchTerm;
    $args['v'] = '1.0';

    $url .= '?'.http_build_query($args, '', '&');
    $url .="&rsz=". 8;


    $ch = curl_init()or die("Cannot init");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    $body = curl_exec($ch)or die("cannot execute");
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($body);


for($x=0;$x<count($json->responseData->results);$x++){
$url_all .="#$*@#" . $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
$visibleurl .="#$*@#" . $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
$title_all .="#$*@#" . $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
$content_all .="#$*@#" . $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;


}
```

**EDIT

This Code works well sometimes, other times it doesn't, Is it a problem of google or something else. I get this error

> $json->responseData->results for this showing "Trying to get property of non-object in"

Comment: Please post what you expect and what you get.

Comment: This Code works sometimes well but sometimes it doesn't, Is it a problem of google or something else. I get error  $json->responseData->results for this showing "Trying to get property of non-object in"

Comment: Sourav,  next time please edit your post to include it in.  I have done it for you this time.  And I have upvoted your question, now that it is better.

Comment: Do u have any idea why it's not working??

Comment: Sorry, no.  Otherwise I would have replied.  But seems to me that your search term is probably not valid.  I assume that the searchterm is input by user.  You need to cater for when teh input is not valid and when the api returns nothing.

Comment: Lol. Same query make problem , but some times give correct answer